# Create function in interface with name from const in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, socket.io

Is it possible to create function in interface with name from const? I have const where I have all event names and I want to create `ServerToClientEvents` interface for SocketIO.

I can write something like this and it will work

```
interface A {
    "funcName": () => void
}
```

But can I create functions in this interface with names from `FunNames`?

```
export const Events = {
    user_updated: "user:updated",
    empty: "empty"
}

interface ServerToClientEvents {
    Events.empty: () => void;
    Events.user_updated: (user: User) => void;
}
```

Comment: *"But can I create functions in this interface with names from FunNames?"* What's `FunNames`? Please show an example of it. Or did you mean `Events`?

Comment: Did you want `ServerToClientEvents` to have a `user_updated` property (the name it has in `Events`) or a `"user:updated"` property (the *value* of `Events.user_updated`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Events` isn't dynamic, maybe [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) can do the job.

```
export const Events = {
    user_updated: 'user:updated',
    empty: 'empty',
} as const;   //const assertion

interface User {
    id: string;
}
interface ServerToClientEvents {
    [Events.empty]: () => void;
    [Events.user_updated]: (user: User) => void;
}
```

Comment: That creates an interface with a `"user:updated"` (not `user_updated`) property. I've [asked them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75683702/create-function-in-interface-with-name-from-const-in-typescript/75683806?noredirect=1#comment133524488_75683702) which they want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and a nested [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) testing the key we're mapping to see if it matches a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) (so we detect whether we need the `user` parameter):

```typescript
export const Events = {
    user_updated: "user:updated",
    empty: "empty",
};

type ServerToClientEvents = {
    [Key in keyof typeof Events]: Key extends `user_${string}` ? (user: User) => void : () => void;
};

const goodExample: ServerToClientEvents = {
    user_updated(user: User) {},
    empty() {},
};

const badExample: ServerToClientEvents = {
    //^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−− Property 'empty' is missing in type '{ user_updated(user: User): void; }' but required in type 'ServerToClientEvents'.ts(2741)
    user_updated(user: User) {},
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAUBsEMGMFMAWB7SATeAnAUASwHYAuWAZnPKAKoDOWoA3tqM6PtALbwBco1hmBAOYBubAF9s2eAA8ADskyFQsZPj6gAogDd4RaqAC8DJiwCutTAH1TstNGJoeAInNYuNuw6cAaE83jssoQAns4BQcE+4qLYIbIUAMpYOpgAKsgAwpC4uoTaufpGjCygANoA0vDBoASgANZVyCSgcfBNmjp6ALo8ldUyxPho+gAGrlYAJPR8AviCYiOgAPygABTjPDRYAJSGAHygWsi4aKA8q7sGB0cnomIxKmpKgsjIaBrSHLKQ3KBJmCl0lkckR8npDMYSuNrLZ7PA0OsLJsLLt6GJfCVwiELgx0dFJI91AAjaDvT6BH48f6AzLZXJgwiFSEsEAAPXZHM5rMASES83kQTDIeKKaoAcixwVFNX07Fw1GoQhq+BawXioFF9FA0I8cIRGyoKJ4NzQwlAYilRNMSkw8AAjqZcDbTrVWurqVggXTQZ1GaKAHSM1YAJgA7AAWACM2z8WosMM88MRbgNO1xvnuQA)

I've assumed there that the `user_` prefix should mean the function accepts a `User` object, given the code shown in the question, but of course you can tweak that as necessary.

With the given `Events` constant, that mapped typ defines this structure:

```typescript
{
    user_updated: (user: User) => void;
    empty: () => void;
}
```

[image: TypeScript playground with the code in the answer and the mouse hovering over ServerToClientEvents demonstrating that its type is as described]

For readability, you might split out the conditional type:

```typescript
type ServerFunctionType<Key extends string> =
    Key extends `user_${string}`
        ? (user: User) => void
        : () => void;

type ServerToClientEvents = {
    [Key in keyof typeof Events]: ServerFunctionType<Key>;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAUBsEMGMFMAWB7SATeAnAUASwHYAuWAZnPKAKoDOWoA3tqM6PtALbwBco1hmBAOYBubAF9s2eAA8ADskyFQsZPj6gAogDd4RaqAC8DJiwCutTAH1TstNGJoeAInNYuNuw6cAaE83jssoQAns4BQcE+4qLYIbIUAMpYOpgAYqb4sIS4qgAqwfEAPADS8MGgMsT4aPp8AviCAHyGfqCl5ZW6NaAABq5WACT0dUJiPa0soAD8oAAU-Tw0WACUhs1ayLhoEyw8s6sG65toMXGJyVi5yADCkLi6hNoP+kaMkwDa7aAEoADWZcgSKAzoDNDo9ABdHhJTApdKZbJ5ArwEplRqiMQxFRqJSCZDINAaaQcWSQbigGEpK63e5EJ56QzGSb9ay2ezwNDzCyLCyrehiXyTcIhfYMAXRSTY9QAI2ghOJgTJ0IumGpdwe9MILyZLBAAD0DYajXrAEhEZrNEEwyHiinKAHJhcE7d99OxcNRqEJvvhgcjQHb6KAWR52ZyFlReTwNlthKAxM7paYlJh4ABHUy4FNob2++L+ymXG7qungrV2gB0WtmACYAOwAFgAjMtWsG2Q4uW4Iysxb5MUA)

Comment: If there are more keys or unique parameters it may be better to create a map of keys to parameter types. Chaining conditional types slows down the compiler